# How to delete an image from the gallery and storing it to bin through another app programatically?

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

I want to access images from the gallery in my app, and then if I delete the image from my app using URI of the image then it should get stored in the bin of the gallery.

I am able to delete the image using URI but don't know hoe store them in bin of gallery, please help

Comment: What do you consider to be the bin of  a gallery? And why gallery out gallery in?

Comment: @blackapps like we delete an image from gallery then they go bin folder, so the bin is a folder as imunderstand.

Comment: There is no bin folder under Android. Why didnt you check? And... Why gallery out gallery in?